# File from previous step cannot be found in Azure DevOps-Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In a pipeline I have two different steps. The first one generates some files, the second should take these files as an input.

the Yaml for that pipeline is the following:

```
name: myscript
stages:
- stage: Tes/t
displayName: owasp-test
jobs:

- job: owasp_test
  displayName: run beasic checks for site
  pool:
    name: default
    demands: Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT

  steps:

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.sln'
  - task: dependency-check-build-task@5
    inputs:
      projectName: 'DependencyCheck'
      scanPath: '**/*.dll'
      format: 'JUNIT'
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '**/*-junit.xml'
```

the `dependency-check-build-task` returns an XML-File:

```
File upload succeed.
Upload 'P:\Azure-Pipelines-Agent\_work\2\TestResults\dependency-check\dependency-check-junit.xml' to file container: '#/11589616/dependency-check'
Associated artifact 53031 with build 21497
```

The following step (`PublishTestResults`) SHOULD take that file but returns

```
##[warning]No test result files matching **/*-junit.xml were found.
```

instead. I can see that file in the artifact after the pipeline is run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your report is written to `Common.TestResultsDirectory` which is `c:\agent_work\1\TestResults` (for Microsoft Hosted agents), and publish test task looks in `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` which is `c:\agent_work\1\s`.

Please try:

```yaml
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '**/*-junit.xml'
      searchFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble:
[image]
I fixed changing the Agent Specification
[image]